# How to show that $\int\nabla^2\psi_n (x)\overline{\psi_m (x)}dx=0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, observables

Let us consider the three-dimensional time-dependent Schrödinger equation that has the general solution $\psi(x,t)=\sum_n c_n\psi_n(x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar},$ where the functions $\psi_n$ are orthogonal.

How to show that

$$\int[\nabla^2\psi_n (x)]\overline{\psi_m (x)}dx=0.$$

Comment: If the Lapalacian is acting over both $\psi_n$ and $\overline{\psi}_m$, then use the divergence theorem to turn it into a surface integral and argue that it vanishes for well behaved normalizable functions. If the laplacian is only acting over $\psi_n$, then this is proportional to the matrix element $\langle m | p^2|n \rangle$. In that case, it seems to me the result is not necessarily true, as it would depend on the potential $V$ of the system as well as $m$ and $n$. If $V$ is constant then that integral goes as $\delta_{mn}$ as the $\psi_m$ would be eigenfunctions of both $H$ and $p^2$.

Comment: @secavara Yes, I'm considering a system in a general potential.

Comment: I don’t think the result is true in general.  As pointed out by @secavara, it’s easy enough to show, using $\psi_0(x)$ as the harmonic oscillator ground state, that $\psi^{\prime\prime}_0(x)$ is proportional to $\psi_0(x)$ and $\psi_2(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think the result is true in general.  It is certainly not true for the harmonic oscillator ground state where $\psi_0^{\prime\prime}(x)$ is proportional to $\psi_0(x)$ and $\psi_2(x)$.

More generally, recall that the kinetic energy $T=-\frac{1}{2m}\nabla^2$
and that, by assumption of your problem,
$$
H\psi_n(x)=E_n\psi_n(x)=T\psi_n(x)+V\psi_n(x)
$$
so that
\begin{align}
T\psi_n(x)&= E_n\psi_n(x)-V\psi_n(x)\\
T_{mn}&=\int dx\,\psi^*_m T\psi_n(x)= E_n\delta_{mn} - V_{mn} 
\end{align}
so unless the potential is diagonal, the kinetic energy will not be diagonal either, and thus $\psi^{\prime\prime}_n(x)$ will not be a multiple of itself, implying that 
$$
\int dx\,\psi^*_m(x) \left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi_n(x)\right)\ne 0\, .
$$